# Vue button, only call method once values of array/object are checked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a working button that calls a function but I want to add a middle layer where it checks the `status` value of each item in my listItems array to make sure the status is complete on all before calling the method.

THe button call works fine but I'm still struggling with how to check the status of all and fire the error if they aren't all complete or call the method if they are.

Here's the bulk of the code:

```
<button class="btn  btn-block" v-on:click="completeItem" type="button" role="button" id="completeItemButton" aria-expanded="false">
        Complete
    </button>

    <p>Must complete all before closing out the item</p>


    vue code:

        export default{

            data() {
                return: {
                    listItems: [
                        {
                        id: 1,
                        status: 'Complete'
                        },
                        {
                        id: 2,
                        status: 'Complete'
                        }
                        {
                        id: 3,
                        status: 'Open'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            methods: {

                completeItem() {
                    //more code upon completion
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if all items in an array match a condition, you can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Here's an example:

```js
completeItem() {
  const areAllComplete = this.listItems.every(item => item.status === 'Complete');
  if (areAllComplete) {
    // TODO
  }
}
```

Comment: I completely missed the 'every' option, trying this now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` to return a boolean by checking through the array,

try the below code.

```
completeItem() {
   if(this.listItems.some(item => item.status === 'Open') { // returns true if ANY item has a status of Open
      //throw error
   } else {
      //continue
   }
}
```

The reverse approach is to check if every status is 'Complete' using `Array.prototype.every`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
  completeItem() {
                for(let i=0; i < listItems.length; i++)
                     if(this.listItems[i].status == "Open"){
                          alert("failed")
                           i = 10;
                  }
            }
```